# Ansible in AWS, list processing question using ec2_instance_info for several nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am running several Ansible playbooks in AWS and I am having difficulty with a test yaml file. The purpose of the yaml file is to query AWS for a list of servers using a filter and set_fact the instance name, the instance ID the instance size and the private IP.

The code I have is returning only data for the first node in the list and repeats the debug line every 12 lines. All the other lines show no data returned. I am using the ec2_instance_info to get the various data about the instances.

Here is the Ansible yaml file

```
---



# This script gathers the Instance ID's et. al.



- name: Get EC2 Info

  ec2_instance_info:

    region: '{{ aws_region }}'

    aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('ini', 'aws_access_key_id section=saml file=~/.aws/credentials') }}"

    aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('ini', 'aws_secret_access_key section=saml file=~/.aws/credentials') }}"

    security_token: "{{ lookup('ini', 'aws_session_token section=saml file=~/.aws/credentials') }}"

    filters:

     "tag:Name": "test-envMan*"

  register: Instance_ID



- name: Get Instance ID

  debug:

      msg: "{{ item.0 }} | {{ item.1 }} | {{ item.2 }} | {{ item.3 }}"

  with_together:

        - "{{ Instance_ID.instances | map(attribute='tags.Name') | list }}"

        - "{{ Instance_ID.instances[0].instance_id }}"

        - "{{ Instance_ID.instances[1].instance_type }}"

        - "{{ Instance_ID.instances[2].private_ip_address }}"



- name: Gather and Save info

  set_fact:

     Tag_Name: "{{ Instance_ID.instances | map(attribute='tags.Name') | list }}"

     Instance_ID: "{{ Instance_ID.instances[0].instance_id }}"

     Instance_Size: "{{ Instance_ID.instances[1].instance_type }}"

     Instance_PrivIP: "{{ Instance_ID.instances[2].private_ip_address }}"
```

The output shows 12 lines of Ansible "ok" output for each server. The first line of which includes the debug output of the expected fields for the first node.

So 1 line of "ok" log output, then the debug line. Then 11 lines of "ok" log output of the same node. Then 1 line of "ok" output for the second node, the the debug line for the first node. etc.

I need to discover what I am doing incorrectly and how to make it behave.

Any comments, suggestions or pointers are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have dumped the registered variable for closer examination, and to attempt to understand the output. What I have it that the playbook I am running specifies a host group that contains 12 hosts. So the ec2_instance_info is being performed for all 12 hosts. The ec2_instance_info is filtering for the exact same 12 hosts. So the output of 144 lines is understood. The output lines contain 12 "ok" entries for the same host name, the data displayed on those 12 lines of out are for each of the 12 hosts. Only the first entry contains data. All data entries are for the same "node02" and are correct.

Comment: I think that the best solution is to change the ec2_instance_info to run in the implied loop that the playbook runs for the 12 hosts and filter the ec2_instance_info for that single host name. I will be working on that later today and report back the results of that effort. First I need to learn about Ansible loops and then attempt using one.